# How to insert an Attachment into an Access database using PHP?

Tags: php, sql, ms-access

I need to add some files uploaded from an HTML form to an MS Access DDBB.
Using PHP, SQL and ODBC I haven't had any problem queryng to the Access file, except for attachment fields.

```
INSERT INTO TEMAS (DATOSADJUNTOS.FILENAME, DATOSADJUNTOS.FILEDATA) VALUES ("ExampleName.txt", "Wathever") WHERE ID = 4;
```

This query returns the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[07009]: Invalid descriptor index: -1003 [Microsoft][Controlador ODBC Microsoft Access] Argumento no válido. (SQLExecute[-1003] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:260)
```

No matter what I put instead of "Wathever", the error is always the same. Except if it is an empty string, then the query runs with no problem, and actually works, as you can see in the [next image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZ5zE.png)

Any idea of what should I put in the query to make it work, or any other way of inserting an attachment into a MS Access DDBB?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erik is right: You can't insert an Attachment using ODBC. You need to use Access DAO, like so:

```php
$dbe = new COM("DAO.DBEngine.120") or die("Cannot create DBEngine object.");
$db = $dbe->OpenDatabase("C:\\Users\\Public\\Database1.accdb");
$rsMain = $db->OpenRecordset("SELECT DATOSADJUNTOS FROM TEMAS WHERE ID=4", 2);  // dbOpenDynaset
$rsMain->Edit;
$rsAttach = $rsMain->Fields("DATOSADJUNTOS")->Value;
$rsAttach->AddNew;
$fldAttach = $rsAttach->Fields("FileData");
$fldAttach->LoadFromFile("C:\\Users\\Gord\\Desktop\\sample.pdf");
$rsAttach->Update;
$rsAttach->Close;
$rsMain->Update;
$rsMain->Close;
$db->Close;
```

Note that Access DAO is a component of the Access Database Engine, so this approach does not require a full install of the Microsoft Access application.

Comment: Way easier than my proposed solution! My PHP experience is Linux-only, didn't know you could use COM in PHP, and surely didn't know it was that easy.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth - `com_dotnet` is only available in Windows versions of PHP and is usually not enabled by default, but uncommenting the appropriate line in php.ini takes care of that. BTW, you've been making excellent contributions here lately; they are much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you very much!
It worked perfectly well for me after adding:
`[COM_DOT_NET]
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll`
to `my php.ini` config file.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is not possible when only using PHP and ODBC. You will need something that can interface directly with Access through COM or the command-line.

You could create a macro to either import all files from a certain folder in Access, or to listen to the command-line and import a single file. Then you could trigger that using `shell_exec` in PHP. That means you will need to have Access on the server running the commands.

It isn't easy. I can give you pointers on steps if you really want to do this.

See [this google discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/microsoft.public.data.odbc/0O4pzF5U4Ps/HswNfKKlP3IJ) where a Microsoft employee stated ACE ODBC has no support for attachment fields.

(If someone does know a way, I'd be happy to be corrected)

Comment: The problem is that, for certain reasons, I must not edit the Access file, but work with it as it is.
It is hard for me to believe that there is no way of doing it. Let's wait, just in case someone can figure it out.
In case we finally can't do it throgh SQL, the macro and `shell_exec` sounds like a good idea. But the macro should be in a different Access file.

Comment: Putting the macro in a different file makes little difference to it's complexity, so that's a valid way to do it

Comment: @RubénAguado - Erik is right: You can't insert an Attachment using ODBC. However, you don't need to use COM automation or shell_exec; you just need to use Access DAO, which is included with the Access Database Engine components. See my answer for details.